# Will apache mahout or other recommendation system work on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, mahout, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, lenskit

Will graphlab, apache mahout or lenskit work on google app engine ?. If it won't, how will i be able to use collaborative filter on gae ?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem in principal running LensKit on Google AppEngine, but doing the model build will be tricky (you'll need a way to run that job).

Comment: Is Apache Mahout or LensKit still alive for cutting-edge work?

Comment: @RahulParashar LensKit is still very much alive.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Mahout integrates nicely with platforms such as Hadoop for distributed processing of the data. However, most of the algorithms are designed to work standalone as well. You should be able to run them within App Engine without an issue. For scalability though, I would consider switching to Hadoop.